# Ordering specification of UNIX system calls

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, unix, happens-before

System calls in UNIX-like OSes are reentrant (i.e. multiple system calls may be executed in parallel).  Are there any ordering constraints of those system calls in the sense of the C/C++11 happens-before relation?

For example, let's consider the following program with 3 threads (in pseudo-code):

```
// thread 1
store x 1
store y 2

// thread 2
store y 1
store x 2

// thread 3
Thread.join(1 and 2)
wait((load x) == 1 && (load y) == 1)
```

Here, suppose `x` and `y` are shared locations, and all the `load` and `store`s have the relaxed ordering.  (NOTE: with relaxed atomic accesses, races are not considered bug; they are *intentional* in the sense of C/C++11 semantics.)  This program may terminate, since (1) compiler may reorder `store x 1` and `store y 2`, and then (2) execute `store y 2`, `store y 1`, `store x 2`, and then `store x 1`, so (3) thread 3 may read `x = 1` and `y = 1` at the same time.

I would like to know if the following program also may terminate.  Here, some system calls `syscall1()` & `syscall2()` are inserted in the thread 1 & 2, respectively:

```
// thread 1
store x 1
syscall1()
store y 2

// thread 2
store y 1
syscall2()
store x 2

// thread 3
Thread.join(1 and 2)
wait((load x) == 1 && (load y) == 1)
```

The program seems impossible to terminate.  However, in the absence of the ordering constraints of the system calls invoked, I think this program may terminate.  Here is the reason.  Suppose `syscall1()` and `syscall2()` are not serialized and may be run in parallel.  Then the compiler, with the full knowledge of the semantics of `syscall1()` and `syscall2()`,  may still reorder `store x 1` & `syscall1()` and `store y 2`.

So I would like to ask if there are any ordering constraints of the system calls invoked by different threads.  If possible, I would like to know the authoritative source for this kind of questions.

Comment: That's where mutexes, semaphores come into play. What you described is a race condition. System calls, as documented, would be marked as thread safe, but not all of them are. Handling threads is the programmer's responsibility, not the system itself! Buggy threading apps is a recipe for the scenario of race conditions.

Comment: The C/C++11 semantics allows race conditions on the atomic locations with the relaxed orderings.  In essence, I would like to the the semantics of relaxed atomic accesses, with race conditions possibly "benign", and system calls.

Answer (score 1):

A [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (those listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) is an *elementary* operation, from the point of view of an application program in user land.

Each system call is (by definition) calling the kernel, thru some *single* [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) instruction (`SYSENTER`, `SYSCALL`, `INT` ...); details depend upon the processor (its [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set)) and the ABI. The [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29) does it business (of processing your system call - which could succeed or fail), but your user program sees only an elementary step. Sometimes that step (during which control is given to the kernel) could last a *long piece of time* (e.g. minutes or hours).

So your program in [user land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userspace) runs in a low level virtual machine, provided by the [user mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes) machine instructions of your processor augmented by a single "virtual" system call instruction (able of doing any system call implemented by the kernel).

This does not forbid your program to be buggy because of race conditions.